# Group Dynamically created objects

Tags: c#, dynamic

At the moment I click 'Add Title' button and it will dynamically create these line of objects.

[image]

This is the C# Code I have used:

```
private void btnAddTitle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        CurrentSortItem++;
        SortItems.Add(CurrentSortItem);

        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

        ComboBox y = new ComboBox();
        y.Name = "Combo" + CurrentSortItem;
        y.SelectedItem = CurrentSortItem;
        y.Height = 25;
        y.Width = 45;
        y.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        y.Margin = new Thickness(20, 15, 0, 0);

        foreach (int item in SortItems)
        {
            y.Items.Add(item);
        }

        TextBox x = new TextBox();
        x.Name = "Title" + CurrentSortItem;
        x.Text = "Title...";
        x.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
        x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        x.Height = 25;
        x.Width = 200;
        x.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        x.Margin = new Thickness(12, 15, 0, 0);

        sp.Children.Add(y);
        sp.Children.Add(x);

        spStandard.Children.Add(sp);

}
```

The Foreach loop in the middle of the code counts how many times I have clicked the button and then in the combo box will display how many titles there is and then you can change the position of that title.

**Question**

How can I group the title objects (ComboBox & Textbox) so that when I change the position of the titles they will move to that position?

**EDIT**

I think I know that I needed to change this line and make it into a GroupBox?

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
```

Change to:

```
GroupBox sp = new GroupBox() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
```

But Then the `Orientation` but doesn't work ...

Comment: you can put your `StackPanel` inside new `GroupBox`

Comment: @Grundy Trying to do this new, I have created a new instance of `GroupBox` called `gb`. Where would I add them to the `GroupBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try put your StackPanel inside new GroupBox like this

```
private void btnAddTitle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    CurrentSortItem++;
    SortItems.Add(CurrentSortItem);

    GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

    ....
    gb.Content = sp;

    spStandard.Children.Add(gb);

}
```

Comment: There is no property for `.Children` for `GroupBox`.

Comment: @user3129331 yep, i want show idea, what you use? wpf? winforms? possibly you need add tags

Comment: Sorry should of added in my question. I am using WPF.

Comment: Thanks man, worked perfectly. I think now the hardest bit will be changing the positions on the GroupBox -.- Thanks for your help.